# Сортировка отрицательных элементов матрицы по возрастанию

Tags: c++

В этом алгоритме происходит вертикальная сортировка отрицательных элементов по убыванию, вроде  как. Помогите переделать наоборот (по возрастанию). Положительные элементы остаются на своих местах.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int sortirovka(int **mas1, int m, int n) {
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j; k<m; k++)
            {
                if ((mas1[j][i]<mas1[k][i]) && (mas1[j][i]<0))
                {
                    temp = mas1[k][i];
                    mas1[k][i] = mas1[j][i];
                    mas1[j][i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Sorted matrix: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << mas1[i][j] << setw(3);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int getInt()
{
    int i;
    while (!(cin >> i))
    {
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cout << "nepravilno. povtorite.\n";
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{

    int **mas;
    int m, n;
    cout << "Stroki i stolbci:" << endl;
    m = getInt();
    n = getInt();
    mas = new int*[m]; // выделение памяти под массив указателей 
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        mas[i] = new int[n];
    cout << "Vvedite elementi v massiv:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            mas[i][j] = getInt();
        }
    }
    cout << "Matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << setw(4) << mas[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
    sortirovka(mas, m, n);

    delete[]mas;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if ((mas1[j][i]>mas1[k][i]) && (mas1[j][i]<0))

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо изменить условие сортировки на противоположное:

```
 if ((mas1[j][i] < mas1[k][i]) && (mas1[j][i] < 0))
```